# Show output of command run using rails runner in shell script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, sh

I'm writing an executable shell script that does something in the rails console using rails runner. How do I see the results of the ruby command made and print them to the screen.

I tried running the script with -v for verbose but I still wasn't able to see what occurred.

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo rails runner "Model.print_something"
```

Comment: What happens when you execute `sudo rails runner "Model.print_something" ` directly from terminal?

Comment: I guess you want to use [`rails console`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console) instead, since [`rails runner`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) says _runner runs Ruby code in the context of Rails non-interactively_.

Answer (score 6):

Use `puts`
`sudo rails runner "puts Model.print_something"`